# How to convert a list of key-value pairs into list of objects in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, algorithm, mapping

I need a "quick and easy" way of converting this:

```
var raw = 
[
 [{"key":"key1v", "value":"value1v"},{"key":"key2v", "value":"value2v"}], 
 [{"key":"key3v", "value":"value3v"},{"key":"key4v", "value":"value4v"}]
]
```

into something like this:

```
var data = 
[
 {key1v:"value1v",key2v:"value2v"},
 {key3v:"value3v",key4v:"value4v"}
]
```

so in the raw data, the key and value are always named "key" and "value"
in the output data the value of the "key" have to be the key itself and as value the value of the "value key"

i hope it doesn´t sound to confusing..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I understand you need something like this?

```
raw.map(line => {
    return line.reduce((acc, item) => {
        acc[item.key] = item.value
        return acc
    }, {})
})
```